# Solved: OpenVPN Import Config Help Needed: Why am I getting a Proxy Tab Instead of Identity Tab?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

With Ubuntu 20.04 when I create a new VPN connection by importing an OpenVPN config I get 4 tabs across the top and it works:

- General
- Identity
- IPv4 Settings
- IPv6 Settings

With Ubuntu Studio 20.04 I loose the identity tab and get a proxy tab instead. How do I make this work with the OpenVPN config file?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` installed. Identity tab from gnome is now called VPN tab in XFCE with the same fields. After installing the package, the options I had under Identity tab are now available in VPN tab.